# How to generate Path with DateTimeFormat for pattern yyyy/mm/dd/HH

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, amazon-s3, jodatime

I am using spark/scala to load files from s3. My files are located under :

```
s3://bucket/yyyy/mm/dd/HH/parts...files
```

I need to generate the file paths with startDate(string) and endDate(string)

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeZone}
import org.joda.time.Days
import org.joda.time.DurationFieldType
import org.joda.time.LocalDate
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val startDate = "2016-09-25T04:00:00Z"

val endDate = "2016-10-23T04:00:00Z"

val s3Bucket = "s3://test_bucket/"

def getUtilDate(timestamp: String): java.sql.Date =  new java.sql.Date(new DateTime(timestamp, DateTimeZone.UTC).toDate().getTime())

val start = new LocalDate(getUtilDate(startDate))

val end = new LocalDate(getUtilDate(endDate))

val days: Int = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays

    val files: Seq[String] = (0 to days)
      .map(start.plusDays)
      .map(d => s"$s3Bucket${DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd/HH").print(d)}/*")

val testFiles =  sc.textFile(files.mkString(","), 20000)

val df = sqlContext.read.json(testFiles)
```

Since sqlContext.read.json() doesn't take multiple paths.

But this doesn't give the HH. It shows as `s3://test_bucket/2016/09/26/��/*`

Can someone tell me why the HH shows as ��. Is there any way I could get all the hours between two days i.e. between `"2016-09-25T04:00:00Z" and "2016-10-23T04:00:00Z"`
like

```
  s3://test_bucket/2016/09/25/04/*.....
           to......s3://test_bucket/2016/10/23/04/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used [`LocalDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) which is a date-only class, it explicitly does not contain time information (this is different to `java.sql.Date` which contains time and date info). Therefore Joda cannot render the "HH" as hour, as it does not have that info.

Try instead:

```
val startDate = "2016-09-25T04:00:00Z"

val endDate = "2016-10-23T04:00:00Z"

val s3Bucket = "s3://test_bucket/"

def getUtilDate(timestamp: String): org.joda.time.DateTime =
  new DateTime(timestamp, DateTimeZone.UTC)

val start = getUtilDate(startDate)

val end = getUtilDate(endDate)

val days: Int = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays

val files: Seq[String] = (0 to days)
  .map(start.plusDays)
  .map(d => s"$s3Bucket${DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd/HH").print(d)}/*")

println(files)
```

### Update: to list all the hours between the days

To list each hour between the two DateTimes, you need to loop from `start` to `end`, using "plusHours" each time. In most languages you'd use a "for" loop for that, but Scala doesn't have a C-style for loop. There are two main ways to do this in Scala; I've shown both below:

```
val startDate = "2016-09-25T04:00:00Z"
val endDate = "2016-10-23T04:00:00Z"

val s3Bucket = "s3://test_bucket/"

def getUtilDate(timestamp: String): org.joda.time.DateTime =
  new DateTime(timestamp, DateTimeZone.UTC)

val start = getUtilDate(startDate)
val end = getUtilDate(endDate)

val fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd/HH")
def bucketName(date: DateTime): String = s"$s3Bucket${fmt.print(date)}"

{
  // Imperative style:
  var t = start
  val files = mutable.Buffer[String]()
  do {
    files += bucketName(t)
    t = t.plusHours(1)
  } while (t.compareTo(end) < 0)

  println(files)
}

{
  // Functional style:
  @tailrec
  def loop(t: DateTime, acc: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = t match {
    case `end` => acc
    case _ =>
      loop(
        t.plusHours(1),
        acc :+ bucketName(t))
  }

  val files = loop(start, Vector())

  println(files)
}
```

Comment: This just gives the hour as 04 for all the days. Is there any way I could get all hours between the days ?

Comment: Is there any way I can get in 24 hours format. The hours I am getting is like PT336H

Comment: "Hours.hoursBetween" just gives a number of hours, rather than a range you can iterate over. I've put a couple of options for listing all hours in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ChronoUnit` to get the HOURS difference between two dates.

```
val minutes = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(dateTime, LocalDateTime.now())
```